# pivot table in sql oracle without aggregations and constant expressions

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I want to make a kind of pivot table, but the problem is that the columns where the pivot is done, must be equal to this_year and next_year. I explain with an example.

```
with
  property(prop_name,  prop_val, planned_year) as (
    select 'BANKING',  'true' , '2018'   from dual union all
    select 'IT'     ,  'false', '2019'  from dual union all
    select 'TELECOM',  'false', '2019'  from dual union all
    select 'MEDIA'  ,  'false', '2020' from dual union all
    select 'APPLE'  ,  'true' , '2018'  from dual union all
    select 'MANGO'  ,  'true' , '2019'   from dual union all
    select 'ORANGE' ,  'false', '2019'   from dual union all
    select 'CARROT' ,  'false', '2019'  from dual union all
    select 'IT' ,  'true' , '2020'   from dual
  )
select *
from   property
pivot  (listagg(prop_val, ',') within group (order by null) 
        for planned_year in ('2019' this_year, '2020' next_year))
;
```

that the result I want to get, except that the pivot must be on the planned year of this_year (so not hardcoded 2019). I tried this:

```
with
  property(prop_name,  prop_val, planned_year) as (
    select 'BANKING',  'true' , '2018'   from dual union all
    select 'IT'     ,  'false', '2019'  from dual union all
    select 'TELECOM',  'false', '2019'  from dual union all
    select 'MEDIA'  ,  'false', '2020' from dual union all
    select 'APPLE'  ,  'true' , '2018'  from dual union all
    select 'MANGO'  ,  'true' , '2019'   from dual union all
    select 'ORANGE' ,  'false', '2019'   from dual union all
    select 'CARROT' ,  'false', '2019'  from dual union all
    select 'IT' ,  'true' , '2020'   from dual
  )
select *
from   property
pivot  (listagg(prop_val, ',') within group (order by null) 
        for planned_year in (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate) this_year, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sysdate)+1 next_year))
```

but then I get the error:

```
"non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values"
```

Can someone help to do the trick?

Comment: Please show the results that you want.  A non-working query is not a good way to express your intents.

Comment: Like I mentionned, the result that I want is the result of the first query. But like I mentionned too, instead of hardcoding '2019' and '2020' I want to take the year of current year and the year of next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `listagg()` with `case` here:

```
with
  property(prop_name,  prop_val, planned_year) as (
    select 'BANKING',  'true' , '2018' from dual union all
    select 'IT'     ,  'false', '2019' from dual union all
    select 'TELECOM',  'false', '2019' from dual union all
    select 'MEDIA'  ,  'false', '2020' from dual union all
    select 'APPLE'  ,  'true' , '2018' from dual union all
    select 'MANGO'  ,  'true' , '2019' from dual union all
    select 'ORANGE' ,  'false', '2019' from dual union all
    select 'CARROT' ,  'false', '2019' from dual union all
    select 'IT' ,      'true' , '2020' from dual)
select prop_name,
       listagg(case planned_year when to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy') then prop_val end, ',') 
         within group (order by null) this_year,
       listagg(case planned_year when to_char(add_months(sysdate, 12), 'yyyy') then prop_val end, ',') 
         within group (order by null) next_year
  from   property
  group by prop_name
  order by prop_name
```